# how can i use this find array and match in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, meteor, lodash

This is my data - how can I find itemId in the array.

```
let itemId=['001', '002', '003'] 
const data = [
  { id: 1, itemId: '001' },
  { id: 2, itemId: '002' },
  { id: 3, itemId: '003' },
];
```

This is my function in lodash but it does not work.

```
  _.find(data, ['itemId',{$in: itemId}])
```

Comment: whats your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#intersectionWith) to get all items from `data`, which id appears in the `itemId` array:

```js
const itemId=['001', '003'];
const data = [
  { id: 1, itemId: '001' },
  { id: 2, itemId: '002' },
  { id: 3, itemId: '003' },
];

const result = _.intersectionWith(data, itemId, ({ itemId }, id) => itemId === id); 

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the exact use-case for this function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter all the item in `data` array that have `itemId` included in `Ids` array, you can try available supported `filter` method without using `lodash`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const itemIds=['001', '003'];
const data = [
  { id: 1, itemId: '001' },
  { id: 2, itemId: '002' },
  { id: 3, itemId: '003' },
];

console.log(data.filter(item=> itemIds.includes(item.itemId)));
```